# 3rd party libraries works with lua, not with mod_lua

Tags: apache, lua, mod-lua

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696771/how-to-setup-mod-lua-in-apache-to-access-third-party-lua-modules) and:

1. There's no working solution proposed
2. I'm not running Windows but Linux
3. It's a home-made compilation
4. running `httpd-2.4.9`

So here's what I tried so far, but without success:

- follow this suggestion "[where do I put 3rd party lua modules](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_lua#Where_do_I_put_3rd_party_Lua_scripts.2Fmodules.3F)"?
- tried to add all possibilities of PATH for Lua in my vhost conf:

  ```
  LuaPackageCPath /web/htdocs/olivier/doonoo/2/
  LuaPackagePath /web/htdocs/olivier/doonoo/2/
  LuaPackageCPath /web/htdocs/olivier/doonoo/2
  LuaPackagePath /web/htdocs/olivier/doonoo/2
  LuaPackageCPath /web/htdocs/olivier/doonoo/2/?.so
  LuaPackagePath /web/htdocs/olivier/doonoo/2/?.so
  LuaPackageCPath /web/htdocs/olivier/doonoo/2/?
  LuaPackagePath /web/htdocs/olivier/doonoo/2/?
  LuaPackageCPath /web/htdocs/olivier/doonoo/2/
  LuaPackagePath /web/htdocs/olivier/doonoo/2/
  LuaPackageCPath ./?.so
  LuaPackagePath ./?.so
  LuaPackageCPath ./
  LuaPackagePath ./
  LuaPackageCPath ./?
  LuaPackagePath ./?
  ```
- tried to put `lfs.so` in my http folder: `/local/install/httpd-2.4.9/modules/lua`
- tried to put `lfs.so` in my lua shared `/usr/local/share/lua/5.2`
- tried to put `lfs.so` in the more generic shared `/usr/local/share`
- tried to put `lfs.so` in the shared http modules `/opt/httpd-2.4.9/modules/`

And now I still haven't found a working solution. Any idea?
By the way I can use `r:notice()` to write some information, so is there a way to dump the `path` and/or `cpath` that lua is using?

In my files, when I have the directive `require "bb"` in the file `aa.lua` and `bb.lua` is in the same path as the `aa.lua`, it works. If I try to do `export LUA_PATH=` and restart my webserver, the directive `require "bb"` doesn't work anymore in `aa.lua`. This implies that the environment variable `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` have some effect on the Apache `mod_lua`.

Now I tried something else: dynamic library. I do this:

```
# lua
Lua 5.2.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> a,b = package.loadlib('/usr/local/lib/posix_c.so', 'fcntl')
> print (a,b)
function: 0x7fbda3f845b0        nil
>
```

This means it tried *successfully* to open + get the `fcntl` function coming from `posix_c.so`.

Now if I try to add this code into my lua file for `mod_lua` like this:

```
function handle(r)
    r.headers_out['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, must-revalidate'
    r.headers_out['Expires'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'
    r.content_type = 'application/json';

    local a,b = package.loadlib('/usr/local/lib/posix_c.so', 'fcntl');
    r:puts(tostring(a)..','..tostring(b))
    return apache2.OK
end
```

I got this output:

```
nil,/usr/local/lib/posix_c.so: undefined symbol: luaL_setfuncs
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307312/lua-error-loading-module-undefined-symbol-lual-setfuncs), I guessed what went wrong: I had installed 5.2.1 version and `mod_lua` was compiled with 5.1. So I removed the 5.2.1, all 5.2 links, and re-compiled the `luaposix` lib. Now the Webpage gives me this: `function: 0x220bce0,nil` which means it successfully opened the library.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made it!

Two things were blocking, and I hope to help other ones if they have the same problem:

1. Wrong version number. `mod_lua` was 5.1 and `lua` installed was 5.2. Solution: remove 5.2 and install 5.1, then recompile all needed modules
2. bad `*.so` location. This command helped me to solve the problem: `r:puts(tostring(package.cpath) .. ',\n')`. It shows the path where `lua` is looking for the dynamic libraries. And no one matched where my `lfs.so`, `posix_c.so`, and `posix.lua` were. Thus I've made the folder `/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/` (which is very "clean" name and location to me) and copied those files there.

Now everything works.